# Unable to pass url parameters into the class method in GAE python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to pass some parameters from URL to my google app engine Python apps class method, but i'm not getting the parameters printed.
Here is the python code

```
    class CheckResponse(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, resp):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(resp)


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/mail', MainPage),
    ('/', ShowHome),
    ('/checkResponse?(.*)', CheckResponse)
], debug=True)
```

Here is the URL `www.example.com/checkResponse?Id=10&Res=Yes`
1) Why is the resp not getting printed.
2) i would also like to know to if there is way to print the value of passed in parameters directly without parsing the response url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this document to get the request data like your ID and Res : http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html

```
class CheckResponse(webapp2.RequestHandler):   # webapp2

    def get(self):

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(self.request.GET['resp'])

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/mail', MainPage),
        ('/', ShowHome),
        ('/checkResponse', CheckResponse)      # changed
    ], debug=True)
```

Comment: already did, and dat is how i came with the above code...would be helpful if you can u point out some thing specifically